# How do I autochange the name of radio buttons from while loop? php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the scenario. in my database, I have like 4 questions. each questions have individual 5 radio buttons. I tried to retrieve the information from database. it shows my list of questions and radio buttons individually, but the BIG problem here is they are in the same group. example. in question 1, I picked 1st radio button, then in question 2, I picked the 2nd radio button. in question 1, the radio button I choose disappeared. so basically. the whole loop have single radio button name. how do I fix this dynamically? like auto change of radio-button-name for each question?

```
<form method='post' action='test.php'>
<?php

include 'db_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
#if ($num_results > 0) {
#}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    extract($row);

    echo $row['test1'];

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question_button' value='1'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question_button' value='2'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question_button' value='3'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question_button' value='4'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question_button' value='5'>";
    echo "<br>";

}






$testbutton = isset($_POST['question_button']) ? $_POST['question_button'] : "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $testbutton;
} 


?>

<html>




<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>

</form>


</html>
```

[image: here is the sample question]

P.S. Edit. my original intention is to add or get the sum of the radio buttons. what syntax should i use?

Comment: What you want change the name of your radio button???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to change button name dynamically 
change like following

```
$question=0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    extract($row);

    echo $row['test1'];
    $question++;
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$question." value='1'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$question." value='2'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$question." value='3'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$question." value='4'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=".$question." value='5'>";
    echo "<br>";

}
```

`$question` is just for example,

you can change redio button name according to your need.

Comment: @gigs happy to help you buddy if you think this is answer , mart it as answer , 
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your database query is producing, but at a guess, I'd say you should be assigning a radio button id to your question in the database field. Then, when you get the results back, you can assign it with something like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    extract($row);

    echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['question_name']."' value='".$row[question_id]."'>";
    echo "<br>";
```

}

This should make every radio box unique so long as the data in the database is unique. If this doesn't help, may I see the results of the database query and I can edit my answer.

Comment: so, you may use the previous answers however no matter what data you pull through, they will always be numbered from 1 to infinity depending on how large your foreach loop is. If you wish to have more control of the data, then I'd advise you add two columns to your database table "question_name" and "question_id", then use then to generate the radio buttons. when you have 15 inputs with only numbers for id's, it can get very messy and confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the radio button a group name differently as bellow example

```
// 1. Get the handler for counter.
$counter = 1;

// 2. Iterating through the results.
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {

    $name = "question_" . $counter . "_button";

    extract($row);

    echo $row['test1'];

    echo "<input type='radio' name=$name value='1'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=$name value='2'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=$name value='3'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=$name value='4'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name=$name value='5'>";

    // Increment the counter by 1 for each question.
    $counter += 1;

}
```